# why is my question closed as unclear what you're asking?

Tags: discussion, edits

[I think my question is pretty clear](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/101486/60939)

> I would like to Merge customer_id from table user to table cust where
>   customers_firstname AND customers_name match

And I attached two images
In fact it was answered immediately
it was upvoted

someone edited my question as code

```
I would like to Merge customer_id from table user to table cust where customers_firstname AND customers_name match
```

And my question was closed as

> closed as unclear what you're asking

once it was incorrectly edited as code it was unclear, all you saw was 2 images and a line of code.

Comment: well if it wasnt closed as "unclear" then it's certainly a dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The displayed close reason reflects a simple majority of the five community close votes cast.

The question isn't at all unclear to me, so that is not the reason I chose personally when voting.  As I recall, I voted to migrate it to Stack Overflow, which is often a better fit for more basic questions.

Looking at the question history, I cannot immediately see why anyone would vote to close it as "unclear what you're asking" at any stage, but it could be closed for other reasons: as a duplicate, too localized, or for migration to SO.

The individual vote reasons are not visible to me, and perhaps not even to moderators, I'm not too sure about that. Perhaps there were two votes to close as unclear, and the other three votes were split over three different reasons.

So, it seems to me the question is closed (to new answers) correctly, just for the 'wrong' (or at least, 'unhelpful') displayed reason. Sorry about that.

Comment: don't you think it's irrelevant?, 3 users agree it should be closed for different reasons all 3 agree that it's clear, 2 users agree it should be closed since it's unclear, you have 3 against two = clear, 5 agree it should be moved or closed, _not clear_ wins

Comment: @yesitsme your comment is unclear to me.  I'm voting to close it.

Comment: @yesitsme If I vote to close a question as e.g. too broad, it doesn't necessarily mean I don't also consider it unclear. (Actually, sometimes it is really hard to choose between these two particular reasons.) But regardless of that, which reason do you propose to show in the discussed scenario? None of the reasons has the *majority* of votes – therefore, a different rule should be used. Choosing the reason that's got more votes than *any other **one*** is a perfectly sensible rule. Anyway, maybe the real issue in this situation is that only one reason gets chosen for display.